# Is it possible to read HTTPOnly cookie in ReactJS using ServerSide Rendering

Tags: reactjs

in one of my project i am getting User identification data from reverse proxy server (Webseal) in httponly cookies and i need to retrive these cookies to retrive data from backend API,I know its not possible to read httponly cookie with any script code.
can it be done using server side renedering using express.Front End Code is written in ReactJS

Thanks

Comment: yeah you can check response cookies. this is the article I found https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_9.0.1/com.ibm.isam.doc/wrp_config/concept/con_mgng_cookies.html regarding it

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can read them in your `backend` make the API requests from your server and then render the response based on that.

Echoing the cookie data inside an `script` tag, would be also possible, but would be an dirty hack, as it defeats the purpose of the `HttpOnly` flag.